# Highlighting FIXME-tags in right editor margin in Eclipe

Tags: eclipse, tags, task, todo

Eclipse shows a blue rectangle in the right margin of structured text-editors to indicate the location of task-tags like `// TODO` or `// FIXME`. Is there a way to change the color of the boxes to red for high-priority tasks like `// FIXME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color in the right hand vertical ruler is set in `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations` - the `Task` annotation. Unfortunately there is no separate setting for high priority tasks.